# Line graph with lower and higher value color indicator in FLutter

Tags: flutter, dart, linechart

Is there any package have line graph with lower and higher value color indicator if value above are below range in Flutter. I spent lot of time online I didn't any solution.

Can any one help how to do implement line graph like as below image ?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need a line annotation: https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/line_charts/line_annotation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts/install) library
and look at [this](https://flutter.syncfusion.com/?_gl=1*1fhc41x*_ga*MTM5MTcyMDMwOS4xNjg0OTI0NTcy*_ga_WC4JKKPHH0*MTY4NDkyOTA3MS4yLjEuMTY4NDkzMDUwNS4yOS4wLjA.#/cartesian-charts/axis-features/plot-band) graph

Select line in right. And there are many graph type in left.